# Unable to create notebook in Jupyter notebook windows

Tags: python, windows, permissions, directory, jupyter-notebook

After opening my jupyter notebook console from command line when I am trying to open new python 3 notebook I am getting an error within a popup which says.
Though I am present in the same directory "Data Visualization with Python".

```
The error was: Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Himanshu Poddar\\Desktop\\Specialisation\\Data Science IBM(Python)\\Data Visualization with Python\\Untitled.ipynb'
```

[image]

Note : I have tried all possible ways in the suggestions and none of them worked for me.

Comment: It could be because of a permission issue. Did you try to run as administrator?

Comment: How do I run jupyter notebook as adminstrator ??

Comment: Right click, run command prompt as administrator. Then type in jupyter notebook in it.

Comment: I doubt permissions would be an issue on a subdirectory of the user's own Desktop directory, and even if that were the case, the error would be a `PermissionError`. The OP needs to run Python from the command line and confirm that `os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\Himanshu Poddar\\Desktop\\Specialisation\\Data Science IBM(Python)\\Data Visualization with Python')`. Don't assume something like "I am present in the same directory".

Comment: And that returns me True.

Comment: Before saving type `pwd()` and execute, what result did you get? Its just a check to get present working directory